# "Heron's proof of AL,BK.CF in Euclid's Figure meet in a point" in God created the Integers.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I was going through the section "Heron's proof of AL,BK.CF in Euclid's Figure meet in a point", in God Created the Integer's book . The statement of problem and its proof are both in very vague form. While searching the internet, all I found was link to the "The Thirteen Books Of Euclid", which also has exact same vague statement and proof. It seems Hawkins lifted it straight from that book. Any how, I want to know the exact problem statement and proof.

Comment: I suppose you are asking about the proof given in Heath's commentary to Euclid, [on page 366 of Vol. 1](https://archive.org/details/euclid_heath_2nd_ed/page/n379/mode/2up). But you cannot expect everybody to have that book at hand, hence you should explain better the matter and what exactly you don't understand in that proof.

Comment: There were some types in God Created the Integers. which is not there in the link you mentioned. Hence, I understood the proof from the link you mentioned.